# Why is my comparison of char array length not working at this instance?

Tags: c

UPDATE: It seems that this code is actually fine, but perhaps a problem with my third party compiler Dev C++...

I am currently trying to figure out why this code won't compile and is repeatedly giving me a error saying "source file not compiled".

It seems to work if I try the statements separately(remove two of the if or else statements), but once all three are together it fails to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char str1[15] = "a";
   char str2[15] = "b";
   int ret;



   ret = strcmp(str1, str2);

   if(ret < 0)
   {
      printf("str1 is less than str2");
   }
   else if(ret > 0) 
   {
      printf("str2 is less than str1");
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("str1 is equal to str2");
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with my declaration of the char array?

I am using a third party compiler called Dev c++ if that helps.

Comment: the code seems good. try to use this main definition: `main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: It didn't work, I'll have to switch back to Ubuntu to run this then, it's probably my compiler program's problem..

Comment: hmm that seems weird. what exactly is the compiler output?

Comment: It just says "compile Failed" I will post a screen shot for you anyways,

Comment: Perhaps post code is different from the actual code.

Comment: No it's the same, I just did a copy paste. A moment please, resizing image to meet standards.

Comment: Damnit  .., I cannot post image because my reputation points is below 10..

Comment: I can confirm it compiles here fine too.

Comment: Here is a photobucket link, http://i534.photobucket.com/albums/ee347/shanamaigo/Untitled.png

Comment: Well, anyhow, it seems that it is just a problem with my third party compiler I guess if it's working for everyone else here. I'll eventually boot into ubuntu to run it.

Comment: Compilation appears to have been successfully.

Comment: Yes, that is the scary part..the log shows that it was fine, but a message keeps saying it failed and as a result, no exe was created so I cannot test it on windows haha.....

Comment: try change the folder and name of the output file(.exe).

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. If rebuilding a project didn't work, try installing new Dev C++.
Source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/